# Create Excel File With Limited Libraries in Java

Tags: java, excel, file, pega

I'm working in a framework that makes extensive use of excel documents, but the only imports it's using to do so are listed below:

```
java.io.*;
java.util.*;
java.util.regex.*;
java.util.zip.*;
javax.xml.parsers.*;
javax.xml.transform.*;
javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
org.w3c.dom.*;
```

Because my workplace may not allow me to get the apache poi jar, how would I even begin to assemble an excel document using the above libraries?

The framework I'm working in is PRPC 7.x - most of the code it uses is proprietary and either hidden or incredibly inconvenient to get to, so it's rough trying to follow the breadcrumbs and mimic existing functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of `Excel` files. The one is `BIFF` (Binary Interchange File Format) saved as `*.xls` files. The other is `Office Open XML`, a `ZIP`ed directory structure containing `XML` files saved as `*.xlsx` files. The latter you can assemble using the showed libraries.

You can simply create a simple `*.xlsx` file using `Excel`. Then open this `*.xlsx` file using a `ZIP` software. Now you can have a look at the directory structure of that `ZIP` archive and at the content of the `XML` files in it.

Now the challenge is to create the needed `XML` files keeping the proper relationships between them and to pack them as an `ZIP` archive using the proper directory structure and then naming that `ZIP`archive `*.xlsx`.

Belive me, it **is** a challenge ;-).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to use apache you could still look at how they do it and mimic that code.

Comment: That depends on why he is not allowed to use apache - if over licensing or patent worries then they might object to even reading the code

Answer (score 0):

go through their OOTB activtiy MSOParseExcel activtiy ... there they zip the excel file -> unzip it and then parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 OOTB activities using which we can generate the XLS. - ExportToExcel in @baseclass - ViewExportToExcel in Rule-Obj-HTML.

One of this should help, let me know if you need any more info.

## RULESWARE